# Culprit of Dependency

Tags: c#, dependencies

When I compile a C# project, I get:

```
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: 
Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Abstractions 6.1.1436 requires 
Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services (= 6.1.1436) but version Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services 
7.0.1001 was resolved
```

I don't actually have any package in the .csproj file which depends on Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Abstractions, so it must be further down the tree. Is there any way to print a dependency tree or otherwise figure out which package has this dependency?